# how to find connected WiFi has internet on or off in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3, android-wifi

```
networking() {
  let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
    alert('network connected!');

    setTimeout(() => {
      alert("Your network type "+this.network.type)             
    }, 3000);
  });
}
```

> I have connected to WiFi
>
> It's showing connected to WiFi. //that was no problem
>
> So How do I check the status of internet connection of WiFi? i.e. ON or OFF.
>
> In Ionic 3

how i can do this???

[ref link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/network/)